# Sum simultaneously 3 dimensions of 4-dimensional matrix

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, matrix

I have 4d matrix, `mat4`. Instead of using `np.sum(mat, axis=)` and defining `axis` 3 times for sum three dimensions, is there a way I can sum many dimensions of matrix, simultaneously?

```
#Sum `mat4` except `axis=0`

mat4 = np.random.rand(2,3,4,5)
matsum = np.sum(mat4, axis=3)
matsum = np.sum(matsum, axis=2)
matsum = np.sum(matsum, axis=1)

print matsum.shape
>> (2L,)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`axis` keyword can be either an `int` or a `tuple`, so
you can simply use

```
np.sum(mat, axis=(1, 2, 3))
```

From [`np.sum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html) docs:

> If axis is a tuple of ints, a sum is performed on all of the axes 
>   specified in the tuple instead of a single axis or all the axes as before.